# Get the Exit status for failed Spark jobs when submitted through Spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, apache-spark-standalone

I am submitting spark jobs using spark-submit in standalone mode.
All these jobs are triggered using cron.
I want to monitor these jobs for any failure.
But using spark-submit if any exception occurs in the application (Ex. ConnectionException) the jobs are terminated and i get 0 as the exit status for the spark-submit.
Also on the Spark-UI it shows the Job status as FINISHED.
What can be done to get the failure of spark jobs in case on any Exception occurs?

Comment: which resource management & job scheduling you are using? For example YARN or Mesos.

Comment: I am using spark standalone for resource management

Comment: Spark Rest API have to provide such info: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spark-submit --status` (as described in [Mastering Apache Spark 2.0]).

```
spark-submit --status [submission ID]
```

To check its status.

1. You can submit your job by calling external process (spark-submit) & read the output stream to parse and extract `submissionId` .
2. Then, check your job status by calling the above process.

Comment: Yes, i got that but we will get the [submission ID]  from the spark web-ui, And I want this monitoring to be automated

Comment: You can submit your job by calling external process & read the output stream to parse and extract `submissionId` . Then, check your job status

Answer (score 0):

Spark-submit submits an application, not a job. So you naturally see the exit code 0 and **FINISHED** if application started and stoped successfully whether any job is failed or not.

To be able to get a failure code, you need to make a change to the job you are submitting by spark-submit and modify the exit code it producing when a critical job is failed.

You can monitor the job status from with in submitted spark job, for example before the context close or exiting. You can use this:

```
JavaSparkContext sc;
... 
JavaSparkStatusTracker statusTracker = sc.statusTracker();
...
final SparkJobInfo jobInfo = statusTracker.getJobInfo(jobId);
final JobExecutionStatus status = jobInfo.status();
```

If the job is failed (status == FAILED), you can trigger exiting the application with code different to 0

```
 System.exit(1);
```

Which will allow application properly to close Spark context and finish. Then you will able to check the exit status of your spark-submit command, since you are launching in standalone mode.

**Note:** For standalone mode you even do not need to use the Spark-submit in general. The jar can be launched as *java -jar ...*, it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't ask for this, but I would strongly recommend you to run Spark applications using [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/), not cron. It provides [an integration with Apache Spark](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark/stable/index.html), which takes care of many things. One of them is this problem you've discovered.

[SparkSubmitOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark/stable/operators.html#sparksubmitoperator) solves this problem by tailing and parsing driver's logs to extract the resulting Spark's job status code.

However, if you want to implement the log parsing yourself, you can take a look at the `_process_spark_submit_log` method in the [airflow.providers.apache.spark.hooks.spark_submit](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.html) code to get some inspiration of how it's usually done in production systems.